# Webauthn API and external devices?

Tags: javascript, authentication, webauthn

I want to implement an authentication on my hybrid web app based on [WebAuthnAPI](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/webauthn).

What Iam trying to do now is that a user can login via fingerprint or USB also on a mobile device.

Is this possible with an adapter + USB fingerscan like [this](https://www.amazon.de/Mini-USB-Fingerabdruck-Leser-PQI-passender-multi-biometrischer-Fido-Sicherheitsschl%C3%BCssel/dp/B06XG4MHFJ/ref=asc_df_B06XG4MHFJ/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=214109653348&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=7144833503497836831&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9042046&hvtargid=pla-297455792879&psc=1&th=1&psc=1)
or with an adapter + USB 2FA device like [this](https://www.amazon.de/Yubico-Y-123-FIDO-U2F-Security/dp/B00NLKA0D8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer isn't a simple yes or no, due to the current implementation state of webauthn. From a desktop perspective, you should be good to go with both devices. If you want to make use of the full feature set of webauthn, such as resident keys, I'd advise to go with the newest yubikey devices as the support the new FIDO2 protocol (as opposed to the older FIDO UDF).

On mobile, things become more complicated. On iOS, support for webauthn is as good as non-existant. Apparently, it's an experimental feature in the latest releases, but I've yet to see any reports of it working correctly (most likely because apple still doesn't expose it's NFC hardware). On android, I'd advise to go with a yubikey NFC device as support seems to be the best. Some android devices are an authenticator themselves and keys will be stored in the secure enclave of the device (so you won't need an external authenticator).

Please note that this information is highly reliant on current software implementations and that this could soon change with the release of (among others) iOS 13.